# How do I alter the n-th line in multiple files using SED?

Tags: bash, sed

I have a series of text files that I want to convert to markdown. I want to remove any leading spaces and add a hash sign to the first line in every file. If I run this:

```
sed -i.bak '1s/ *\(.*\)/\#\1/g' *.md
```

It alters the first line of the first file and processes them all, leaving the rest of the files unchanged.

What am I missing that will search and replace something on the n-th line of multiple files?

Using bash on OSX 10.7

Comment: What's the version of `sed` on your system. It works well in Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: @kev so it does -- but that's actually contrary to documented behavior, which indicates that the `-s` flag should be necessary for the individual files to be treated as separate streams. That said, OS X doesn't use GNU tools, so he'll probably need to go the shell-loop approach.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that sed by default treats any number of files as a single stream, and thus line-number offsets are relative to the start of the first file.

For GNU sed, you can use the -s (`--separate`) flag to modify this behavior:

```
sed -s -i.bak '1s/^ */#/' *.md
```

...or, with non-GNU sed (including the one on Mac OS X), you can loop over the files and invoke once per each:

```
for f in *.md; do sed -i.bak '1s/^ */#/' "$f"; done
```

Note that the regex is a bit simplified here -- no need to match parts of the line that you aren't going to change.

Comment: Thanks Thats exactly what I needed to process all the files. I altered your second answer to target the first line: for f in *.md; do sed -i.bak '1s/^ */#/g' "$f"; done

Comment: @FrederickYocum Thanks for pointing out that oversight; I've applied it to the answer as an edit.

Answer (score 0):

XARgs will do the trick for you:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs

Remove the *.md from the end of your sed command, then use XArgs to gather your files one at a time and send them to your sed command as a single entity, sorry I don't have time to work it out for you but the wikiPedia article should show you what you need to know.

Comment: The problem isn't sending them to sed as a single entity -- the problem is that sed by default treats any number of files as a single stream, and thus line-number offsets are relative to the start of the first file.

Comment: @Charles Duffy: put this in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -rsi.bak '1s/^/#/;s/^[ \t]+//' *.md
```

You don't need g(lobally) at the end of the command(s), because you wan't to replace something at the begin of line, and not multiple times.

You use two commands, one to modify line 1 (1s...), seperated from the second command for the leading blanks (and tabs? :=\t) with a semicolon. To remove blanks in the first line, switch the order:

```
sed -rsi.bak 's/^[ \t]+//;1s/^/#/' *.md
```

Remove the \t if you don't need it. Then you don't need a group either:

```
sed -rsi.bak 's/^ +//;1s/^/#/' *.md
```

-r is a flag to signal special treatment of regular expressions. You don't need to mask the plus in that case.

Comment: That's a good point -- the English prose in which the question is written is ambiguous in terms of whether the leading-space modification applies to all lines rather than the first (though other folks answering, myself included, have taken the opposite meaning, with the "first line" restriction intended to apply to both changes). I'd be interested to get clarification from the original author in terms of the intended meaning.

Comment: ...actually, I think the "leaving the rest of the files unchanged" phrase from the question cuts against this interpretation.

Comment: Ah - now I understand. My interpretation was `I want to (remove any leading spaces) and (add a hash sign to the first line in every file).`, but now your interpretation `I want to (remove any leading spaces and add a hash sign) to the first line in every file.` seems more plausible to me, given the example code. It was all only about the sed option -s, then.